# How to exclude a folder from tslint?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, lint, tslint

I like to exclude the `test` folder form linting with tslint in vscode. So I have placed an exclude into my tslint.json config file. Unfortunately the exclude statement is not working. Does any one know how to set the exclude up?

```
 {
    "exclude": "tests/**/*.ts",
    "rulesDirectory": ["node_modules/tslint-microsoft-contrib"],
    "rules": {
        "export-name": true,
        ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this is an open feature request. 
Further information can be found here: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/73

**Update:**
for those who use VSCode with tslint as editor/linting you can add the following to the VSCode config:

```
 // Configure glob patterns of file paths to exclude from linting
"tslint.exclude": "**/PATH_eg_TESTS/**/*.ts"
```

Comment: It worked for me in the array form:
`"tslint.exclude": "**/schematics/**/files/*.ts"`
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Latest update: this can now be set in in tslint.json (the following configuration works with tslint 5.11)

```
{
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "bin",
      "build",
      "config",
      "coverage",
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Should be noted that the final PR uses `linterOptions` rather than `cliOptions`: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/2409#issuecomment-289464766

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in tslint: 6.1.2.

> In the root folder where tslint.json is located create the file path to directory.

```
"linterOptions": {
  "exclude": [
    "libs/folder/folder/**",
    "apps/stuff/stuff/**"
  ]
}
```