# Set .history folder as ignored by intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to ignore **.history** folder from intellisense.
Now it looks like this when I start typing Focus:

[image]

As you can see intellisense will offer me every Identical class found in .history folder and this is very very confusing (and find correct one).

I try find something in vscode settings, and on [editor site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) but no success.

.history folder is ignored from git, display in explorer, and tslint:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.history": true ...
},
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.history/**": true ...
},
"tslint.exclude": ["**/.history/**"] ...
```

How to achieve ignore .history from intellisense?

---

*Next part is based on the answer from Matt*

**An important assumption:**

Visual Studio Code itself does not contain automatic import and **you need an extension for it**.

**Solution:**

I am using extension **Auto Import** (*steoates.autoimport*) which contains the setting `autoimport.filesToScan`. I changed default value from `"**/*.{ts,tsx}"` to `"{src,e2e,node_modules}/**/*.{ts,tsx}"` and now everything work as I expected.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388529/how-to-exclude-a-folder-from-tslint

Comment: Sorry, but is it not relevant, as I wrote, tslint exclude is already set (and not helping to avoid this import mess). And also intellisense (vscode core) is completely different functionality than lint (extension).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those suggestions are coming whatever extension you have installed that is providing auto-import functionality. Please check to see if that extension has its own `exclude` setting that you also need to configure

Comment: You are absolutely right. I will expand my question with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.json`, you could add this:

```
"autoimport.filesToScan": "./index.{ts,tsx} ./App.{ts,tsx} ./src/**.*.{ts,tsx}"
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
"autoimport.filesToScan": "./{index,App,src/**}.{ts,tsx}"
```