# How to exclude folder in vscode C# IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have a problem. When I'm programming, the local history extension does backups of files, but C# [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) scanning these files. The problem is when local history will do backup with an error in code. After this, in my VScode I see a lot of errors from backup files. I tried to exclude .history folder in the VScode, but it didn't help. I would like to know how to exclude this folder from C# IntelliSense or exclude these communicates in vscode.

Comment: Have you tried filling the pattern for excluding files and folders in Settings (type "files.exclude" in search)?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494280/set-history-folder-as-ignored-by-intellisense