# TSLint not respecting folder exclusions

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm getting warnings about files in node_modules despite the following tslint.json. How do I totally prevent tslint from running on node_modules?

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "config/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**/*.ts",
      "node_modules/**/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "cliOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "bin",
      "build",
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the output on save.

```
Compiling...
Compiled with warnings.

~/node_modules/object-assign/index.
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* ~\node_modules\object-assign\index.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    ~\node_modules\react-scripts-ts\config\polyfills.js
* ~\node_modules\object-assign\index.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    ~\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

I got the cliOptions section from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558738/2312075). If it matters, I created the app with `npx create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts`

Comment: FYI, I deleted and recreated the project and no longer have this issue. I would still be interested in figuring out what happened though.